# Angular Material theme/styles not showing up in Django

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, angular-material-6

So I've written a Django REST Framework API, and am now working on the Angular front end, I serve the angular app through Django using  and calling the appropriate js.

I've specified Angular's build output to be to the same directory as my Django static files directory.

The theming and CSS works when I connect directly to the Angular service (localhost:4200) but not when it is being served through Django (localhost:8000)

I've imported the relevant modules in my material.module.ts and applied a global theme in styles.css.  Any direction?  I don't see any errors anywhere that I can try to diagnose, so I really have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  For anyone else developing with Angular and a DRF backend, but serving through Django:  Make sure to ng build and serve first, then manage.py runserver to let Django collect the updated Angular files.